# Can't install software when c:\Windows\Installer is Junctioned

Tags: junction, ntfs-junction, directory-junction

When I move all files from `c:\Windows\Installer` to `E:\SymLinked\Installer` and then do a `mklink /J c:\Windows\Installer E:\SymLinked\Installer`, reboot, and then try installing software I get errors like these from installers:

[image]

[image]

After making the junction, I've even gone to the `E:\SymLinked\Installer` and made sure all apparently relevant users have Full Control, but still get the same error.

When I remove the junction and copy the Installer folder back to the Windows folder, installs work again.

I've had it working in the past w/out issue, but it seems after a recent update it started doing this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try a symbolic link instead? `mklink /d c:\Windows\Installer E:\SymLinked\Installer`? Then move the contents.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I've put my hands into this longtime irritating behaviour.
After excluding many versions (by checking back and forth), I'm pretty much certain, that it happens when:

- older version of same app was installed
- when installer is msiexec

Fix: uninstall previous version OR temporarily rename/remove `Installer` symlink from `Windows` dir. I've created empty `Installer` dir (original one), but not sure it's necessary.